# Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2' due to an API incompatibility

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, java-17

I am trying to build my office project where I've upgraded from java 11 to 17.

I've updated my maven according to the compatible java version and after getting a a lot of help on the rest of the errors I'm still stuck on this one.

Things I've updated till now:
Eclipse version, java version , java version , surefire plugin details, mirrorOf tag in settings.xml.

Details of the versions are mentioned below :

- Java version - 17 .
- Java Home - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5
- java path - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5\bin  -
- java version in my pom - 17
- maven version installed in my system - 3.8.5
- maven_home - C:\project\Softwares\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.5\bin
- maven in my pom.xml  - 3.8.1

Now after setting up everything , this is the error. Please help me in rectifying this :

```
Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
```

EDIT 1  : Adding the pom.xml 4.0.0

Comment: The plugin version you are using is ca. [10 years old](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin). You should use the most recent version of plugins https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm new to this. Can you please tell me exact thing ? you mean maven version ? or war-plugin version ? My maven war plug in is <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId><version>3.3.1</version> and my maven-compiler plugin is <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId><version>3.8.1</version>

Comment: The plugin version....

Comment: Perhaps showing how your pom looks like might help people help you? Although, don't dump the whole thing if its too big. Perhaps showing the top part where versions are usually displayed and the specific dependency tag for the maven plugin might suffice.

Comment: Hi @brat , I've updated the answer with the response of mvn dependency:tree . Can you please check and help me on that ?

Comment: What helped me to resolve same issue is to define specific version of the war plugin in the root PluginManagement.

Answer (score 9):

Try below options

1. In your pom.xml, configure the below plugins

   - maven-compiler-plugin -> 3.10.1
   - maven-war-plugin -> 3.3.2
2. Try cleaning the project and updating the maven dependencies (right-click project -> Maven -> Update Project)
3. If it doesn't work, there might be an issue with your Maven install.
   You may try uninstalling the M2Eclipse plugin, deleting the .m2 folder on your drive, and then reinstalling M2Eclipse.

---

*PS:*

*I noticed that you have used servlet 3 dependencies in your project. Since you are using java 17, you might upgrade them accordingly to the latest available versions*

Comment: removing the plugins didn't help. I'm unable to rectify now , tried all the steps that have mentioned. Also , can you please elaborate the last line? do you just mean the versions of the servlets dependencies?

Comment: Why is the maven picking 2.2 as a war plugin and not the latest one. tried maven update and clean too.. please refer the edit 2.

Comment: Adding a specific plugin entry for the maven-war-plugin with a recent version number (3.3.2) did the trick for my war build that were failing with the same error as the original question.

Comment: Got my fix with -> maven-war-plugin -> 3.3.2